# Oracle Identity Manager -- Data Refresh from PROD

Tags: oim

I am novice in the OIM field and ran into issues. It would be really helpful if someone helps me out in this context.

OIM currently used for centrally manage authentication and authorization and it has quiet a many custom field in USR table currently in PROD. On top of that, current enhancement we are doing also required additional field in USR table which we are adding through USR FORM changes. The new changes are not in LIVE yet.

The requirement is to do a data refresh from PROD to the environment where UAT would be performed. Since we are not changing the servers where OIM used and only doing DB refresh from PROD, what is the best way to do this activity.

Do we need to do Full DB refresh or partial refresh (only schema oim)?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

There is a document from Oracle on how to perform OIM DB backup/restore.

**OIM 11gR2: Schema Backup and Restoration using Data Pump Client Utility (Doc ID 1492129.1)**

The short resume of the document is that you have to take care of several schemas (OIM, SOAINFRA, MDS, ORASDPM, OPSS). There are some dances around while doing backup/restoration but i don't remember the details. You will figure that out in the process, if you don't have access to the document.